# Expose C++ buffer as Python 3 bytes

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost-python, python-3.2

Using Boost::Python, is there a way to make a raw C++ buffer accessible to **Python 3.2** as a `bytes` object?

There is a Python 2 answer to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232520/how-to-expose-raw-byte-buffers-with-boostpython), but the `PyBuffer_FromReadWriteMemory` function described there no longer exist in Python 3.

**Edit**: thanks to user2167433's answer, what I actually want is a read only [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) object, not a `bytes` object (using a `memoryview` avoids copying the buffer I believe).

Comment: Why a `bytes` object? Is the buffer immutable?

Comment: @delnan Yes the buffer is immutable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Python > 3 and Python <= 3.2:

```
Py_buffer buffer;
int res = PyBuffer_FillInfo(&buffer, 0, data, dataSize, true, PyBUF_CONTIG_RO);
if (res == -1) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
boost::python::object memoryView(boost::python::handle<>(PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(&buffer)))
```

### Python >= 3.3:

The best way I know how is to use PyMemoryView_FromMemory:

```
boost::python::object memoryView(boost::python::handle<>(PyMemoryView_FromMemory(data, dataSize, PyBUF_READ)));
```

memoryview is the Python way to access objects that support the buffer interface.

[C API memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/memoryview.html)
[memoryview class](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview)